# how to filter axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

how to filter axios response? so i need to filter and get filtered response in browser, database is monodb...

```js
const getNodeData = (route, params) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
   axios.get(route, {
    params,
    withCredentials: true
    })
    .then((res) => reslove(get(res, 'data.data', [])))
    .catch((error) =< reject(error))
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways for filtering yor response.

1 - If this filter will occour everytime, then you can need the query in the back end to adjust it.

2 - In the front end, get your response (res) and give a variable that uses a loop for filtering.

Example:

```
const getNodeData = (route, params) => {
  axios.get(route, {
    params,
    withCredentials: true
  })
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.filter("YOUR FILTER CONDITION HERE")
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}
```